# Trying out login page in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying out a login page in using I am using the below code to make it work. I am not sure why isn't it getting to sucess.php even after typing correct user and password.

```
<?php

include("db_config.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

 $myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
 $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']); 

 print_r($mypassword);

 $mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword);

 print_r($mypassword);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $auth = $row['auth'];
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 print_r($count);
 $response = array();

 if($count==1)
 {

   print_r("Login Sucess");
   if($auth==1)
   {
     print_r("Login Sucess");
     $_SESSION['name'] =  $myusername;
     header("location: http://www.abcdef.com/sucess.php"); 
  }
  else
  {
    //Nothing for now... 
    print_r("Nothing for now");
  }
}
else 
{

   print_r("Your Login Name or Password is invalid");

 }
}
?>
```

If I give a wrong password it prints invalid password and the related things that needs to print, but if type correct password it doesn't print anything and doesn't get the next page too.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Enable error reporting and you will see the problem (print_r() before header())

Comment: Was the password created using the same hashing method?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep. That is right.

Comment: When you debug this, what path does the code follow?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: as stated by @phantom doing print_r before header is what may give you the white page of dead. Try putting *ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL)* and *ini_set('display_errors', 1)*. Oh, btw, [using addslashes for escaping may not be the safest way](https://www.google.es/search?q=php+addslashes+for+sql+sanitization), consider migrate to PDO+prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

I do believe its because you are trying to change the header after you have printed something on the page, remove the statements that print on a successful login and just leave the `header` as such:

```
if($count==1)
{
    if($auth==1)
    {
       $_SESSION['name'] =  $myusername;
       header("location: http://www.abcdef.com/sucess.php"); 
    }else{
    //Nothing for now... 
    print_r("Nothing for now");
    }
}else{

   print_r("Your Login Name or Password is invalid");

 }
}
```

Comment: There was no print there. I put the print to see if it was getting inside the condition

Comment: What response do you get after adding `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your page?

Comment: Did you say I need add in top of the my php page if so. I have done it and no changes. :(

Comment: Yes before the include? I will have more of a think

Comment: Yep. Still the same. :(

Comment: To cover all bases try and remove all of the `print_r`s you have

Comment: All Removed...Still the same.

Comment: I even tried lower version still the same.. Now I am running pHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mysql_fetch_array in the following code:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $auth = $row['auth'];
```

Use mysql_fetch_assoc. you can see the differences [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?558526-difference-between-mysql_fetch_assoc-mysql_fetch_array-amp-mysql_fetch_object)

your login is successful but $auth is not getting any values. Which is not letting you redirect to the correct page.

Comment: If that was the case then it should have gone to the else part which  should print ("NOTHING FOR NOW"), but it didn't print anything